# Frequencies are inherently positive physical quantity.... what does it mean?

Tags: frequency, signal-processing, terminology

While I was going through a digital signal processing course, I came to this problem where it says that "Frequencies are inherently positive physical quantity" - *Digital Signal Processing* by John G Proakis, Page 15. I didn't really get the intuitive idea. Can anyone explain this sentence a little bit or suggest some resources?

Comment: `intuitive idea`  ... clap your hands `2` times per second ... now try clapping `-2` times per second

Comment: It fully depends on what simplifications you make. Negative frequencies appear as a concept in signal processing quite often, so even if in practice you don't have negative frequencies they are still used in maths.

Comment: @jsotola: I started clapping my hands, re-read your comment, and stopped clapping.  It made perfect sense.

Comment: Negative frequencies show up in Euler's formula. They don't seem to have physical meaning, but act kind of like shadows in the math which do have real meaning. It's weird.

Comment: Negative frequencies are used to explain, for example, how "amplitude modulation" works. It is only viewed as a "shifting" of the "frequency spectrum" of the "base signal" by the "modulating frequency". The shifting occurs in the "positive" direction and in the "negative" direction.

Comment: If you read about single sideband modulation, you'll appreciate the difference between negative and positive frequencies. When speaking about real signals, they become indifferent though

Comment: same thing as oranges, you cannot have negative ones...however, if you happen to have two oranges and eat one of them its very easy (mathematically) to consider the one you ate as -1 orange

Comment: @DKNguyen it is weird, but this statement: "In the 'real world', time only goes forwards but mathematically, we can consider events in the past of future" seems to help a bit. Not 100% sure why.

Comment: It mean that you can use positive AND negative frequencies to make any "complex" calculus ... and after that, you "retain" the positive frequency solution ...

Comment: related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102528/how-do-you-visualize-negative-frequency-in-time-domain/102535#102535

Comment: another intuitive idea - if you're screwing in a screw by rotating it right 2 full turns per second - how many times are you rotating it left per second? Granted, it doesn't quite work, but it shows how negative frequencies can be useful as intermediates or virtual quanities

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Frequency is how many times something happens every second. So it can't be "minus 5 times a second". However when you do actual signal processing, you'll see negative frequency on the graph too.

Comment: Omg, my least important answer ever gets the most upvotes...

Comment: _"Omg, my least important answer ever gets the most upvotes..."_ This is an inherent feature of how this website works. Short answers to simple questions can be verified (and upvoted) by many, while highly specialized questions only attract the attention of a few selected specialists.

Comment: Moreover, it's not just short and simple, it's an answer for a trivial question. Fifth grade.

Comment: It's a Hot Network Question, so it will attract more votes, than others ([guess how I know](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/306028/duracell-powercheck-how-does-it-work/306031#306031)).

Comment: It's worth noting that the negative frequency components of a signal are indistinguishable from the positive.  It needs to be represented as complex if you want to make the negative half of the spectrum usable.  From an information standpoint, adding a second axis for amplitude translates into opening the negative half of the spectrum.

Comment: @Velvet Originally, the point was to have a place where you can get information that's not otherwise available, by asking others that have experience on the thing. That's why the site requires (required?) users to research before asking. But there's really no good way to align that with website popularity and upvoting.

Comment: When you use complex numbers or I/Q components, you can have negative frequencies - because the signal is not just going up and down every second, but rotating around a circle every second, and it can rotate in either direction. Actual sound waves, for example, do not rotate around in circles, but the circle version shows up a lot in signal processing maths.

Comment: @TQQQ Easy answers can be digested and then upvoted much more quickly.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis I would say negative components don't exist in real signals. By convention we can treat them as complex signals, and then they have equal negative and positive components so the imaginary part cancels out, leaving a real signal.

Comment: @user253751 I see it more that, mathematically, the complex spectrum must be reduced to real signals before it can be manifested in the real world, but it's just a matter of which direction you want to see it from.  Don't make me get into quaternions!

Answer (score 9):

Frequency is related to time. Time in systems is only positive. For theoretical purposes you can consider time to be negative, but in the real world time is always positive

Answer (score 8):

Consider a spinning disc. It can rotate clockwise or counter-clockwise. Clockwise angles \$\theta\$ are considered negative while counter-clockwise angles positive,

The angular velocity \$\omega\$ is the time rate of change (derivative) of the angular position.
$$
\omega=\frac{d\theta(t)}{dt}\tag{equ 1}
$$
which can be positive or negative.

If spinning at a constant rate (periodically) then the equation can be integrated over one rotation to show that:
$$
\omega T=\pm 2\pi
$$
where T is called the period of rotation.
\$2\pi\$ is positive or negative depending on whether the integration is clockwise, or counter-clockwise.

Since frequency is the inverse of period, \$f=\frac{1}{T}\$ then it is always positive as indicated by voltage Spike's answer.

So in the relation:
$$
\omega = 2\pi f
$$

should probably be written
$$
\omega = \pm 2\pi f
$$

When negative frequencies are plotted, they should be considered as angular (phase) velocities as in equ 1.

The angular velocity is sometimes, loosely, called the radian frequency which can be confusing on this point.

This discussion centres on the mechanical rotating disc, but the concepts are routinely applied in all areas of STEM, as well as DSP.

Comment: I think in your example, if constant angular velocity, which could ofc be positive, or negative, there is no AC frequency component. it's just constant motion ... now if you had $$\theta = sin (\omega . t)$$ then you would have a frequency... but now it's a different $\omega$, not $ d\theta / dt$

Comment: θ is an angle so cannot be the sine of an angle. In the answer the angle θ is advancing continuously as it does in every ac signal. A height of a point on the circumference is the ac sinusoid described by \$y=Ymax\sin (\omega t)\$ @PeteW

Comment: hmm... ok I think that would more commonly be denoted $\phi$ , i.e. phase

Comment: @PeteW, the MathJAX inline markdown prefix / suffix is `\$`. It's different to most other stacks.

Comment: @Transistor - thanks

Comment: I think there's a typo: "Clockwise angles θ are considered negative while counter-clockwise angles negative"

Answer (score 1):

In common usage, frequency is an absolute magnitude, and thus positive. This is similar to how [speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed) is positive regardless of travel direction.

- If you count the number of passing street lights to determine your speed, you always get a positive value.
- If you count the number of tick-tock sounds from your clock to determine its frequency, you always get a positive value.

However, this is just a matter of definition. To avoid confusion, the signed counterparts have their own names:

- If you define a positive direction of travel, and then make a U-turn, your [velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity) is negative.
- If you define a positive direction for your clock, and adjust the mechanism to run backwards, its [signed frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_frequency) is negative.

Velocity finds most use in physics problems and rarely in day-to-day life. Signed frequency finds most use in signal processing and rarely in day-to-day electronics.

Comment: A clock that runs backwards will still make tick-tock sounds - depending. If your backwards clock goes tock-tick, I suppose you could count that as a negative frequency.

Comment: @user253751 And a car that returns towards origin will still pass street lights. Endless sequence of tick-tock-tick is just tick-tock-tick in reverse :)

Comment: @user253751: A single sinusoidal frequency component has no inherent directionality, but combinations of signals with known phase relationships can.  If one were to construct a one-second loop of the sound of a gong strike, all frequency components would be multiples of 1Hz, but if one were to negate the frequency of all of them while keeping the same initial t=0 phase condition, the gong would start softly and get louder, before it diminished almost instantly to nothing.  One could achieve the same effect while keeping the frequencies positive if one flipped some of the initial phases...

Comment: ...but for signals that are known to have a consistent phase relationship at a particular time, inverting the frequency would change that relationship.

Comment: Frequency sign can also be used to signify the direction of travel in a transmission line, when analyzing the constructive and destructive interference.

Answer (score 1):

If you're counting cycles in time, frequency is positive. However, the mathematical concept has other, more abstract uses. It is common in Fourier analysis to treat frequency as signed. When using Laplace transforms to analyze linear systems, we use *complex* frequency.

Comment: Yes, in the Laplace domain the prase "comples frequency" is used, but complex "angular velocity" is more correct. \$s=\sigma + j\omega\$  The units are not hertz, but radians/second

Comment: @RussellH Using angular frequency is simply a convenient convention that avoids littering expressions with lots of 2π factors. It's not necessary to the math.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a picture that explains ... what I meant.

The "multiplication of the "vo1" spectrum by a sinusoid (at 10 kHz) give the "vo2" spectrum.
It gives, shifted to the right, the 6 "waves" at 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23 kHz.
It gives, shifted to the left, also 6 "waves" at 1, 2, 3 **AND** -1, -2, -3 kHz (these last 3 are not shown).
These last 3 combine with 1, 2, 3 and give amplitude multiplied by 2.
So, "negative" frequencies are "real" things but only in combination with the real waves at positive frequencies.

What you see in "black" is the recombination (at low frequencies) of the "two" half-spectrums (shifted positive and negative by 10 kHz) which is then "double" amplitude of the six right "waves".

Made with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110).

[image]

And here is the Maple sheet ... which details the "amplitudes".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of frequency.

- "How many times it happens per unit of time"

In this case, it cannot happen a negative number of times, thus frequency is always positive.

- "[Instantaneous frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantaneous_phase_and_frequency)"

If you have a signal \$ s=sin( \omega t + \theta )\$ you can define its phase as \$ \varphi(t) = \omega t + \theta \$ so your signal becomes \$ s=sin( \varphi(t) )\$.

Now if you use complex notation, or if you have IQ modulation so both the real and imaginary part of the signal are transmitted, it becomes:

\$ s=e ^ { \omega t + \theta } = e^{\varphi(t)}\$

So we have \$ \omega = \frac{d\varphi}{dt} \$ and \$ f = \frac{d\varphi}{\pi dt} \$

Basically, the instantaneous frequency is the derivative of phase \$/\pi\$.

There is no reason the sign of this quantity should be constrained to positive. The real and imaginary components model a rotating vector, if what generates the signal decides to have it rotate in the other direction then \$ \frac{d\varphi}{\pi dt} \$ will change sign.

For example, consider three phase power.

\$ L_1 = A cos( 2\pi f t + 0 ) \$

\$ L_2 = A cos( 2\pi f t + 2\pi/3 ) \$

\$ L_3 = A cos( 2\pi f t + 4\pi/3 ) \$

Just like complex signals, or IQ modulation, that's a vector, it rotates, it can rotate in both directions, and the sign of the frequency is the direction or rotation.

If you don't believe frequency can be negative,

1. Write "rpm = frequency *60 *2 /number of poles" on a post-it.
2. Stick it on a three phase induction motor, for example a pump.
3. Swap two phases and start it.

This only works if the sine signal is a vector (ie, you have at least two actual signals). If the sine signal is a scalar, then positive and negative instantaneous frequencies cannot be distinguished.